# What image types does VB6 support?

Tags: graphics, vb6

What specific picture or image types & formats does VB6 support?

I can find specific examples here on SO but I haven't seen any comprehensive information.

I am mainly interested in what can be used "natively" by VB6, though I am sure there are third-party libraries and/or other methods of loading additional image types.

Answer (score 2):

The function [LoadPicture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa264946(v=vs.60)) (loosely) defines what graphics formats are "supported by VB6" in a native sense. Here are the relevant details:

> Loads a graphic into a forms Picture property, a PictureBox control,
>   or an Image control.
>
> ...
>
> Graphics formats recognized by Visual Basic include bitmap (.bmp)
>   files, icon (.ico) files, cursor (.cur) files, run-length encoded
>   (.rle) files, metafile (.wmf) files, enhanced metafiles (.emf), GIF
>   (.gif) files, and JPEG (.jpg) files.

Additional information based on a useful [external post](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?555378-Classic-VB-What-picture-types-does-VB-support-(or-why-wont-VB-load-this-picture-)):

> There are many types of picture files, and some of them have multiple
>   "sub types" too. Unfortunately several popular types have been created
>   (or extended) since VB6 was released, so it does not support them.
>
> **Supported file types**
>
> This is the list of types shown in the help for VB6 (under LoadPicture):
>
> Graphics formats recognized by Visual Basic include:
>
> - bitmap (.bmp) files,
> - icon (.ico) files,
> - cursor (.cur) files,
> - run-length encoded (.rle) files,
> - metafile (.wmf) files,
> - enhanced metafiles (.emf),
> - GIF (.gif) files,
> - and JPEG (.jpg) files.
>
> **A note about icon (.ico) files**
>
> These have evolved over the years, and many of the icons you find on
>   the web are not supported.
>
> VB6 only supports icons that have a size of 32x32 or 16x16, and a
>   color depth of "True Color" (24-bit) or "256 Colors" (8 bit) or less -
>   so no alpha channel (32 bit).
>
> If you find icons that are described as "XP icons" or "Vista icons",
>   they are unlikely to load in VB - if they do, it is because suitable
>   icons are also included in the file too (a .ico file can contain
>   multiple pictures).
>
> You can convert icons to a suitable format using an icon editing
>   program...
>
> **Other file types**
>
> If the file type you want to load is not listed above, you will need
>   to do some extra work.
>
> The easiest way (if you only have a few files) is to use a paint
>   program to convert the picture file to one of the types listed above.
>
> There are many situations where that is not valid (such as when you
>   want the user to be able to load .png files), in which case you either
>   need to find pre-written code (or a component) to load the file for
>   you, or write the code yourself.

Comment: Anybody happens to know where to obtain this pre-written code to load a PNG picture file into VB6 Picture Box?

Comment: @JkyleLandicho https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250980/how-can-one-open-a-png-image-file-with-vb6-into-an-rgb-array-or-r-g-b-array