# Invalid Picture when loading png to Imagine box vba excel

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I receive the error "Invalid Picture" when trying to load a *png* picture to my Image1 box in the userform; not sure how that happens if I have my criteria set to .png.

The image URL should be like entered to Textbox2_img_url

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

  Dim img As String

  img = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Images,*.png", Title:="Please Select a 
  Picture")
 
   If Dir(img) <> "" Then
 
   Me.TextBox2_IMG_URL = img

   Me.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(img)
 
   End If
 

  End Sub
```

Comment: `LoadPicture` [doesn't support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54253745/11683) png.

Comment: `LoadPicture` doesn't support **png** as commented correctly by @GSerg. - As a workaround I posted an alternative procedure via system near application programming interface functions (GDI+ library ). Simply replace your original code line by `Me.Image1.Picture = LoadPictureGDI(img)`  to allow loading Portable Network Graphics (PNG), too.

Answer (score 1):

**Loading also Portable Network Graphics (PNG)**

You might profit from the alternative procedure **`LoadPictureGDI`** via *`GDIPlus lib`*
which is based on an [old post](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/using-png-images-on-a-userform.691847/) from Stephen Bullen
as of *Oct 31th, 2006*, but updated for VBA7 **API calls**.

By using **API functions** *(API - Application Programming Interface)* you have to take care of the different environments. These system functions do demand LongPtr types for pointers to a → handle or → memory location (note the special *PtrSafe* prefix!).

As a window handle is declared as **LongPtr** since *Office 2010* or higher and as **Long** in *versions before*, it is necessary to differentiate between the different versions by **conditional compile constants** (`#If VBA7 Then` .. `#End If`)

**So a possible call in your Userform code might be**

```
    Me.Image1.Picture = LoadPictureGDI(img)
```

**a) Necessary Type & API declarations in code module head**

```
Option Explicit

'Declare a UDT to store a GUID for the IPicture OLE Interface
Private Type GUID
    Data1         As Long
    Data2         As Integer
    Data3         As Integer
    Data4(0 To 7) As Byte
End Type

#If VBA7 Then           
    'Declare a UDT to store the bitmap information
    Private Type PICTDESC
        size As Long
        Type As Long
        hPic As LongPtr
        hPal As LongPtr
    End Type
    
    'Declare a UDT to store the GDI+ Startup information
    Private Type GdiplusStartupInput
        GdiplusVersion As Long
        DebugEventCallback As LongPtr
        SuppressBackgroundThread As Long
        SuppressExternalCodecs As Long
    End Type
    
    'Windows API calls into the GDI+ library
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GdiplusStartup Lib "GDIPlus" (token As LongPtr, inputbuf As GdiplusStartupInput, Optional ByVal outputbuf As LongPtr = 0) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GdipCreateBitmapFromFile Lib "GDIPlus" (ByVal Filename As LongPtr, bitmap As LongPtr) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GdipCreateHBITMAPFromBitmap Lib "GDIPlus" (ByVal bitmap As LongPtr, hbmReturn As LongPtr, ByVal background As LongPtr) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GdipDisposeImage Lib "GDIPlus" (ByVal image As LongPtr) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub GdiplusShutdown Lib "GDIPlus" (ByVal token As LongPtr)
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function OleCreatePictureIndirect Lib "oleaut32" (PicDesc As PICTDESC, RefIID As GUID, ByVal fPictureOwnsHandle As Long, IPic As IPicture) As Long
#Else
    'Declare a UDT to store the bitmap information
    Private Type PICTDESC
        size As Long
        Type As Long
        hPic As Long
        hPal As Long
    End Type
    
    'Declare a UDT to store the GDI+ Startup information
    Private Type GdiplusStartupInput
        GdiplusVersion As Long
        DebugEventCallback As Long
        SuppressBackgroundThread As Long
        SuppressExternalCodecs As Long
    End Type
    
    'Windows API calls into the GDI+ library
    Private Declare Function GdiplusStartup Lib "GDIPlus" (token As Long, inputbuf As GdiplusStartupInput, Optional ByVal outputbuf As Long = 0) As Long
    Private Declare Function GdipCreateBitmapFromFile Lib "GDIPlus" (ByVal Filename As Long, bitmap As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GdipCreateHBITMAPFromBitmap Lib "GDIPlus" (ByVal bitmap As Long, hbmReturn As Long, ByVal background As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GdipDisposeImage Lib "GDIPlus" (ByVal image As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Sub GdiplusShutdown Lib "GDIPlus" (ByVal token As Long)
    Private Declare Function OleCreatePictureIndirect Lib "oleaut32" (PicDesc As PICTDESC, RefIID As GUID, ByVal fPictureOwnsHandle As Long, IPic As IPicture) As Long
#End If
```

**b) Main Procedure `LoadPictureGDI`**

```
' Procedure:    LoadPictureGDI
' Purpose:      Loads an image using GDI+
' Returns:      The image as an IPicture Object
Public Function LoadPictureGDI(ByVal sFilename As String) As IPicture

Dim uGdiInput     As GdiplusStartupInput
Dim lResult       As Long
#If VBA7 Then
    Dim hGdiPlus  As LongPtr
    Dim hGdiImage As LongPtr
    Dim hBitmap   As LongPtr
#Else
    Dim hGdiPlus  As Long
    Dim hGdiImage As Long
    Dim hBitmap   As Long
#End If

    'Initialize GDI+
    uGdiInput.GdiplusVersion = 1
    lResult = GdiplusStartup(hGdiPlus, uGdiInput)

    If lResult = 0 Then

        'Load the image
        lResult = GdipCreateBitmapFromFile(StrPtr(sFilename), hGdiImage)

        If lResult = 0 Then
            'Create a bitmap handle from the GDI image
            lResult = GdipCreateHBITMAPFromBitmap(hGdiImage, hBitmap, 0)
            '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            'Create the IPicture object from the bitmap handle
            '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            Set LoadPictureGDI = CreateIPicture(hBitmap)

            'Tidy up
            GdipDisposeImage hGdiImage
        End If

        'Shutdown GDI+
        GdiplusShutdown hGdiPlus
    End If

End Function
```

**c) Help function `CreateIPicture()`**

```
' Procedure:    CreateIPicture
' Purpose:      Converts a image handle into an IPicture object.
' Returns:      The IPicture object
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Function CreateIPicture(ByVal hPic As LongPtr) As IPicture
#Else
    Private Function CreateIPicture(ByVal hPic As Long) As IPicture
#End If
Dim lResult As Long
Dim uPicInfo As PICTDESC
Dim IID_IDispatch As GUID
Dim IPic As IPicture

'OLE Picture types
Const PICTYPE_BITMAP = 1

' Create the Interface GUID (for the IPicture interface)
With IID_IDispatch
    .Data1 = &H7BF80980
    .Data2 = &HBF32
    .Data3 = &H101A
    .Data4(0) = &H8B
    .Data4(1) = &HBB
    .Data4(2) = &H0
    .Data4(3) = &HAA
    .Data4(4) = &H0
    .Data4(5) = &H30
    .Data4(6) = &HC
    .Data4(7) = &HAB
End With

' Fill uPicInfo with necessary parts.
With uPicInfo
    .size = Len(uPicInfo)
    .Type = PICTYPE_BITMAP
    .hPic = hPic
    .hPal = 0
End With

' Create the Picture object.
lResult = OleCreatePictureIndirect(uPicInfo, IID_IDispatch, True, IPic)

' Return the new Picture object.
Set CreateIPicture = IPic

End Function
```